# Google Play Games Services achievement activity closing immediately

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm updating my game to the new Google Play Serviced library, leaderboards and achievements were already working flawlessly, but now when I try to open the achievement activity, it immediately closes without showing any exception in logcat.
I'm logged in with my google account, which is correctly configured as a test user.

```
public void gameServicesGetAchievements() {
    if (gameHelper == null)
        return;

    Intent i = Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient());
    ((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_ACHIEVEMENTS);
}
```

The activity opens, but closes immediately before showing the achievements list. This is what I get in logcat

```
D/GameHelper(30459): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=9802, resp=RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED
D/GameHelper(30459): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
```

I tried handling the RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED code in my onActivityResult, but nothing changes.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);

    GameHelper helper = resolver.getGameServicesHelper();
    if (helper != null) {
        helper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    if (response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
        helper.disconnect();
    }
}
```

The leaderboards activities start correctly and work flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem... it wasn't a problem in my app, just the Google Play Games app on my device had some corrupted data or something.
I followed the steps here and that fixed it.
http://howlukeseesit.blogspot.it/2014/08/fixing-google-play-games.html

- First navigate to settings > apps and find and tap on Google play
  games.
- Next tap uninstall updates, then tap clear data.
- Next go back
  to the apps section and find Google Play Services, tap that then tap
  Manage space and then tap on clear all data.
- Now all you have to do
  is go into the Play store and manually update Google Play Games.

Comment: Firstly, thank you, this has just saved me hours of work. Secondly, I found that just clearing data for Google Play Services was sufficient.

Comment: Whilst this did work, I also had to restart my device before Google Play Games would update successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer from me too. I had the same problem when i was calling for Leaderboard. You saved me many many hours...