# Google Play Game Services - Leaderboard closes authomatically

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've got 4 LeaderBoards in my application.
I add score to one of them with:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, "xxxx", 10);
```

Now I would like to see results:

```
   startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                "xxxx"),REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

Activity starts and it's loading its content but it closes automaticaly before anything is loaded. Other three Leaderboards works fine and I can open them (until I add score to them).

I implemented onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent)
```

Result code is 10001 which means RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED, but reconnection doesn't help. What helps is reinstalation of app...

Comment: I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507922/google-play-games-services-achievement-activity-closing-immediately) but didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#updating_the_players_score) correctly. A [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507922/google-play-games-services-achievement-activity-closing-immediately) was raised with calling Achievements (it even has the same result code you have!) and was handled by uninstalling updates and clearing data. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks helped me too : D