# Waiting room finishing with result RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am creating a RealTime Multiplayer Game and after the Waiting Room Activity is starting, the Activity is finishing immediately with result code 10001 (GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED)

This behavior is strange because the room is still created, and if another player is starting the Waiting Room for a random auto-match, Google will auto-match them even if the Waiting Room was closed.
This behavior is not happening to all the Users. Only for a few users.

This is the code that starts the Waiting:

```
    final int MIN_PLAYERS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(RGoogleAPI.getGoogleApiClient(), room, MIN_PLAYERS);
    mWaitingRoom = room;

    // show waiting room UI
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
```

I want to mention that even if I want to show the Leaderboard or the Achievements, is stil returning the code RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED and the Leaderboard is finishing

Answer (score 0):

The Constant Value: 10001 or [`RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes.html#constants) is the result code sent back to the calling Activity when a reconnect is required.

The `GoogleApiClient` is in an inconsistent state and must reconnect to the service to resolve the issue. Further calls to the service using the current connection are unlikely to succeed.

You can also find in [`getAchievementsIntent()` and `getAllLeaderboardsIntent()`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient#public-methods) that R`ESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED` may be returned as the resultCode in `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` if the GamesClient ends up in an inconsistent state.

Check the solution here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507922/google-play-games-services-achievement-activity-closing-immediately), it might also help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem but i didnt find any solution. Can u help me?