# Calling startActivityForResult getAllLeaderboardsIntent crashes

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, startactivityforresult

I have a problem a few days now and I can not find a solution.

I am migrating an old Game I have made to the new Google play game.

I encounter the following problem:

When I call:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_LEADERBOARDS);
```

The Activity suddenly closes and the the game returns to my Main Activity.

The weird is that this problem happens ONLY after I submitScore with the following code line:

```
if(longMyTopScore<45001) {Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_higher_total_scores), longMyTopScore);}
```

I have read here that i had to clear cache and data from Google Play game service [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507922/google-play-games-services-achievement-activity-closing-immediately). I did that and then it was again ok until i submitScore. Then the problem is here again.

I tried to handle that from startActivityForResult and I see that there is a resultCode 10001 (RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED).

I dont know what to do. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), REQUEST_LEADERBOARDS);
```

to

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

Use `getLeaderboardIntent` instead of `getAllLeaderboardsIntent` as instructed in the [Displaying a leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards) tutorial in Google Play games.